# Why is my function re-wrapping the input elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

for some reason my input elements are getting wrapped twice or sometimes even more when I refresh the screen.

I've tried to check if the parent is e-wrap and if not add the e-wrap but the result is nothing and causes the placeholders to not show at all.

```js
var InputClass = BaseClass.extend(function(inputName) {
  this.type = 'InputClass';
  this.dom = jQuery(inputName);

  if (this.dom.attr('placeholder')) {
    if (this.dom.data('flaying-placeholder'))
      return false;

    this.dom.data('flaying-placeholder', true);
    this.dom.wrap('<div class="e-wrap"></div>');

    var ph = this.jq('<div class="placeholder-text"></div>');

    this.dom.data("placeholder", this.dom.attr('placeholder'));

    ph.html(this.dom.attr('placeholder'));
    ph.css({
      'font-size': this.dom.css('font-size')
    });

    if (this.dom.val() != '') {
      this.dom.attr('placeholder', '');
      ph.css({
        'top': '-' + this.dom.css('font-size')
      });
      ph.addClass('active');
      ph.show();
    } else {
      ph.hide();
      ph.removeClass('active');
    }

    this.dom.bind('focus', function() {
      this.dom.parent().addClass('focused');
      this.dom.attr('placeholder', '');
      ph.css({
        'left': '12px',
        'top': '-1px'
      });
      ph.show();
      ph.addClass('active');

      if (this.dom.val() != '') {
        ph.css({
          'top': '-' + this.dom.css('font-size')
        });
      } else {
        ph.animate({
          'top': '-' + this.dom.css('font-size')
        }, 500);
      }
    }.bind(this));

    this.dom.bind('focusout', function() {
      this.dom.parent().removeClass('focused');
      this.dom.attr('placeholder', this.dom.data("placeholder"));
      if (this.dom.val() != '') {
        ph.show();
        ph.css({
          'top': '-' + this.dom.css('font-size')
        });
        ph.addClass('active');
      } else {
        ph.hide();
        ph.removeClass('active');
      }
    }.bind(this));
    this.dom.before(ph);
  }
}).statics({}).methods({
  toggleDialog: function(text) {},
});
```

The result would be the inputs not getting wrapped multiple times when I refresh the screen or return the screen.

Comment: *"I've tried to check if the parent is e-wrap and if not add the e-wrap but"*  Where?  i don't see that logic in your question

Comment: There's no checking before `this.dom.wrap('<div class="e-wrap"></div>');`.